# How to deploy a contract on Infura with Web3.py v4

Tags: web3.py

I am trying to deploy a contract to a test network like Ropsten.

I am running through Infura using the `HTTPProvider`. I need to be able to sign the deployment of the contract locally, but can not figure out how to do this with the current API.

Any pointers?

Comment: The testnet name you likely mean is Ropsten.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you already have a private key available, using something like [extracting a private key from a geth keyfile](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#extract-private-key-from-geth-keyfile), and that you are using Web3.py v4.2.0.

The general approach is to:

- construct your contract with any initialization arguments
- build the transaction for the contract constructor
- sign the transaction with your private key
- broadcast the signed transaction
- wait for the transaction to be mined

One convenient way to [build the transaction locally](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.buildTransaction) is to use the [`constructor()` method](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.constructor) on a contract object. For example:

```
deploy_txn = my_contract.constructor(*init_args).buildTransaction()
```

Then, [sign the transaction locally](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-transaction):

```
signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(deploy_txn, private_key)
```

Finally, [broadcast the transaction](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.sendRawTransaction), and [wait for it to be mined](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.waitForTransactionReceipt):

```
txn_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)  
txn_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(txn_hash)
```

To use the contract, you can rebuild the contract object with its new address. The address of your new contract is available at `txn_receipt['contractAddress']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at (my) [`furiate`](https://gitlab.com/veox/furiate) script, which submits transactions to Infura using a local account.

It's slightly dated, and (currently) has a `web3.py` beta in `requirements.txt`, but should work with the latest v4 stable (v4.2.0, I think).

It uses the `eth_account` package separately, but should be possible in about the same way with `web3.py`, which incorporates `eth_account`'s functionality.

---

In particular:

- [opening a JSON keyfile](https://gitlab.com/veox/furiate/blob/5dd6b3b2c62141a19e30f501e833ee145bc3edf8/furiate.py#L24);
- [setting *some* transaction data](https://gitlab.com/veox/furiate/blob/5dd6b3b2c62141a19e30f501e833ee145bc3edf8/schedule.py#L25);
- `nonce`, `chainId` and `gasPrice` are populated separately [around here](https://gitlab.com/veox/furiate/blob/5dd6b3b2c62141a19e30f501e833ee145bc3edf8/furiate.py#L45);
- [signing the transaction](https://gitlab.com/veox/furiate/blob/5dd6b3b2c62141a19e30f501e833ee145bc3edf8/furiate.py#L61), followed immediately by submitting it.

---

P.S. There's a [backup repo on GitHub](https://github.com/veox/furiate) if you don't have a GitLab account, but would still like to "star" it for later. ;)